# Prometheus: How to create an SLI/SLO from blackbox exporter with probe_http_duration_seconds?

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

i try unsuccessfully since some days to create an SLI based on latency to an http endpoint. I have a blackbox exporter and 3 days of data.

I tried lot of thing like this: count_over_time(probe_http_duration_seconds{target_url="xxxx",phase="connect"}[7d] > 0.01)
i got: binary expression must contain only scalar and instant vector types"
I understand what the error message says but really dont understand how to get the info i want.

My average "probe_http_duration_seconds" requests are around 10ms, so i'd like to count each time, the blackbox get an answer over 10ms. Let's say that requests over 10ms are failures. I need to measure these failures.

Answer (score 4):

Just Found how to handle it:

```
quantile_over_time(0.90,probe_http_duration_seconds{app="myapp",env="prd",instance="https://probe-target",job="blackbox",phase="connect"}[15d])
```

works great for measuring Latency SLOs with blackbox exporter

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the percentage of requests with duration exceeding 10ms during the last 7 days:

```
avg_over_time(
  (probe_http_duration_seconds >bool 0.01)[7d:1m]
) * 100
```

It uses the following PromQL features:

- [Prometheus subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/)
- [Bool modifier for comparison operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators)
- [avg_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time) function